# how can I get picture from post that published public "Buy and Sell" group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group, facebook-feed

I need to take a picture from "buy and sell" group... from a regular(public) group I'm took the pictures with attachments but from "buy and sell" group it does not show me. 
I will glad for help

Comment: Pretty sure there is no APIs for buy and sell stuff

Comment: I do accept the title and body of the message but not the pictures and the price